# What is the **latter** referring to?

Tags: meaning

[This article about machine learning](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~pedrod/papers/cacm12.pdf) says:

> Generalizing correctly becomes exponentially harder as the dimensionality (number of features) of the examples grows, because a fixed-size training set covers a dwindling fraction of the input space. Even with a moderate dimension of 100 and a huge training set of a trillion examples, the **latter** covers only a fraction of about 10<sup>-18</sup> of the input space. This is what makes machine learning both necessary and hard.

Is the **latter** referring to "a huge training set of a trillion examples"?

Comment: It's hard to read it any other way.

Comment: I wonder if it's referring to '*Generalizing*' and it's comparing it with the previous '*Overfitting*'

Comment: Welcome to ELL!  "Latter" and "former" generally refer to the most recent thing, like most ***antecedants*** in English.  So -- yes!   Be sure to read the "[Contributor's Guide to ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide)" and [Details Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/details-please).  Keep contributing and welcome!